# error: expected enum but got (raw string) single_capture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, attrs.xml

I'm trying to use custom attributes to make an audio wave form. I used enum only once in this project. First it was working perfect, then this error below appears. I tried to modify it or delete it, but nothing changed. If anyone can help me with this, or if the error in some different module.
Thank you...

```
<declare-styleable name="WaveFormView">
        <attr name="peakMode" format="integer">
            <enum name="peakmode_average" value="0"/>
            <enum name="peakmode_max" value="1"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="secPerBlock" format="float"/>
        <attr name="blockWidth" format="float"/>
        <attr name="topBlockScale" format="float"/>
        <attr name="bottomBlockScale" format="float"/>
        <attr name="showTimeText" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="blockColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="blockColorPlayed" format="color" />
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textBgColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

> Execution failed for task ':app:processBenchmarkResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> com.elton.chatday.app-mergeBenchmarkResources-4:/values/values.xml:11591: error: expected enum but got (raw string) single_capture.
> error: failed linking references.